# Spark DataFrame - drop null values from column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe :

```
    val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", ArrayBuffer(null,"bar",null)), ("bar", ArrayBuffer("one","two",null)))).toDF("key", "value")
    df.show

    +---+--------------------------+
    |key|                     value|
    +---+--------------------------+
    |foo|ArrayBuffer(null,bar,null)|
    |bar|ArrayBuffer(one, two,null)|
    +---+--------------------------+
```

I'd like to drop `null` from column `value`. After removal the dataframe should look like this :

```
    +---+--------------------------+
    |key|                     value|
    +---+--------------------------+
    |foo|ArrayBuffer(bar)          |
    |bar|ArrayBuffer(one, two)     |
    +---+--------------------------+
```

Any suggestion welcome . 10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an UDF here. For example with a `flatMap`:

```scala
val filterOutNull = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => 
  Option(xs).map(_.flatMap(Option(_))))

df.withColumn("value", filterOutNull($"value"))
```

where external `Option` with `map` handles `NULL` columns:

```
Option(null: Seq[String]).map(identity)
```

```
Option[Seq[String]] = None
```

```scala
Option(Seq("foo", null, "bar")).map(identity)
```

```
Option[Seq[String]] = Some(List(foo, null, bar))
```

and ensures we don't fail with NPE when input is `NULL` / `null` by mapping

```
NULL -> null -> None -> None -> NULL
```

where `null` is a Scala `null` and `NULL` is a SQL `NULL`.

The internal `flatMap` flattens a sequence of `Options` effectively filtering `nulls`:

```scala
Seq("foo", null, "bar").flatMap(Option(_))
```

```
Seq[String] = List(foo, bar)
```

A more imperative equivalent could be something like this:

```scala
val imperativeFilterOutNull = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => 
  if (xs == null) xs
  else for {
    x <- xs
    if x != null
  } yield x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: using UDF:

```
 val filterNull = udf((arr : Seq[String]) => arr.filter((x: String) => x != null))
 df.withColumn("value", filterNull($"value")).show()
```

Option 2: no UDF

```
df.withColumn("value", explode($"value")).filter($"value".isNotNull).groupBy("key").agg(collect_list($"value")).show()
```

Note that this is less efficient...

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria) it has: com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.functions.arrayExNull

from the documentation:

> Like array but doesn't include null element